# Simplifying an expression with Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Can anyone simplify the following expression? I guess something from Fourier transform can help:

$$f(\omega) = \lim_\limits{R \to \infty}  \frac{1}{R^2} \int_{r=0}^{R}{re^{i \omega r^{-\gamma}}} \mathrm{d}r$$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $\gamma > 2$.

Comment: Look at the individual terms for large $R$.  What do we see is happening for say, $c\ge 0$?

Comment: So the imaginary unit is not constant? :-)

Comment: Please remove the $a(1-(1+bR)e^{-cR})$ part, it is trivial that it has no relevance here.

Comment: If you substantially change the question (in this case removing $a$) when there are already answers, please notify the answers' authors so they can adapt their answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the exponential in the integral, only the constant term survives, yielding $R^2/2$, so the limit is $1/2$. This should in fact work for any $\gamma\gt0$, though one might have to argue more carefully in that case why the operations are allowed.

Comment: Something might not be correct here. Just consider the integration over the second term of $e^{tr^{-\gamma}}$. We have
$\lim\limits_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{R^2 (2-\gamma)} \left[ -r^{2-\gamma}\right]_{0^{+}}^{R}$. So, we may not be able to neglect this term, as $R$ grows large as we always would have zero to power of a negative value ($\gamma > 2$).

Comment: @Hossein: What's $t$? In any case, you can separate the integral from $0$ to, say, $2$ as an additive constant and use the expansion only for $r\gt2$. The series of terms you get from the lower limit $2$ converges to a further additive constant, so it's only the terms from the upper limit $R$ that determine the asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: The actual problem is that I am trying to find moment generating function (MGF) of a random variable $X$, which will be simplified to 

$$E \left[ e^{tX} \right] = \lim_\limits{R \to \infty}   \exp \left\{\frac{1}{R^2} \int_{r=0}^{R}{re^{i \omega r^{-\gamma}}} \mathrm{d}r \right\}$$. 

Now, if the limit of exponent tends to 1/2, then $E \left[ e^{tX} \right] = e^{0.5}$. However, from Taylor expansion we know that $E \left[ e^{tX} \right] = 1 + t E\left[X\right] + t^2 E\left[X^2\right]/2 + \cdots $. These two derivations of MGF do not match, implying that something is wrong

Comment: @Hossein: "The limit tends to" makes no sense. The limit *is* $x$, and the quantity whose limit we take *tends to* $x$. In any case, I don't know what you mean by that limit; perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: You are right. I mistakenly used "the limit tends to". I meant if $\lim_\limits{R \to \infty}  \frac{1}{R^2} \int_{r=0}^{R}{re^{i \omega r^{-\gamma}}} \mathrm{d}r \to 0.5$, then $E\left[ e^{tX}\right] \to e^{0.5}$. It means that all moments of random variable $X$ are zero, including its expected value, variance, etc, which should not be correct in my case. Moreover, using Taylor expansion of $E\left[ e^{tX}\right]$ tells that, if all moments are zero, $E\left[ e^{tX}\right]=1$ not $e^{0.5}$, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Hossein: I'm afraid I can't say much in response to that without knowing your random variable $X$. I don't see any error in the calculation, but of course I might be wrong. Perhaps I'm not allowed to switch the summation and the integration like that, but I'd be surprised. If you want me to comment more, please explicate the entire connection to $X$.

Comment: can I have your email address to ask my question or should ask it directly here?

Comment: @Hossein: We can chat sometime -- but I don't have the time right now -- you could also post your question about this apparent contradiction in a new question here on the site -- I think that might be the best approach, since it's going beyond the original subject of this question.

Comment: I have posed a new quation in 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363393/contradiction-in-moment-generating-function-of-a-random-variable 

where you can find detailed description of $X$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25925/discussion-between-hossein-and-joriki).

Comment: @Hossein: Sorry, I'm busy for the rest of the day, but will look at your new question and will try to contribute tomorrow.

Comment: I found the error! Your integration is correct.